# Show Recent Folders in Title Bar

Tags: file, macos

I love the ability to rename and move documents fro the Title Bar in macOS applications.

The only thing is that the dropdown list for the `Where` field doesn’t include recent folders, so I always have to select `Other…` and select the recent folder from there.

Is there a way to show recent locations in the Dropdown?

I have tried in Preview, and a few third party Apps. They all show the current path hierarchy as well as favorites, and Preview also shows the iCloud drive. None show recent folders.

I am running macOS 13.5 (22G74) on an M1 Mac Mini.